# how to add current class on current page menu

Tags: jquery, url, menu

I am using jquery lava lamp menu.  I want to add current class on li tag not a tag
this is my menu

```
<div>
 <ul class="lavaLamp">
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.php?page=contact">Contact</a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried this.

```
$(function(){ 
  var url = window.location.pathname,  
  urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");         
  $('.lavaLamp li a').each(function(){  
  if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){ 
    $(this).addClass('current'); 
    } 
  });
});
```

I have tried every thing found on web but nothing works for me. I dont know why all codes not working. I have extra subfolder my URL looks like this:
http://example.com/mysite/index.php
http://example.com/mysite/about.php

Comment: GUYS STOP FORMATTING THE NAV from a codeblock. It matters cause it has the class information.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: I was about to go reformat the HTML into a codeblock but then noticed it is the OP who is reverting it each time. hamp13: are you deliberately reverting the formatting of the post or is it happening accidentally?

Comment: @hamp13: Have you checked what the regex is and the strings you are checking with them? The contacts one won't work at least because this.href will contain the query but the pathname call won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem to work. Anyway, here's a solution:

```
$(function(){
 var url = window.location.pathname;  
    var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 $('.lavaLamp li a').each(function(){  
    var currentPage = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    if (activePage == currentPage) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('current'); 
 } 
});
})
```

Note that I use *.parent()* to get *li* element, since you wrote you want to add .current to *li*, not *a*.

Comment: thanks for ur answer ur code works perfectly but i have some problem on my contact page my contact. if i send something to browser i cant able to add the class current. i am using php so must of time my browser look like this somepage.php?cid=12&pid=13 that time ur code dont work can u do some thing about this.

Comment: That's strange. `window.location.pathname` only takes current url (`yourwebsite.com/yourpage.php`) without query (`?param=value`). I've tested this code on my computer, seems to be working even with parameters in the url, so the issue is somewhere else, I think. Can you show a demo of your page with the problem?

Comment: thanks i dont have any problem with ur activePage its takes only url wtihout the values. i think problem is currentPage check this link http://ipoxs.com/lavalamp/ my product and services page is not working.

Comment: Yes, it's because in your `<a>` `href` attribute you have not only `services.php`, but also a query string `?serv=all`, while the script checks if `href` is only equal to `services.php`. To fix that, add this line after you get `currentPage` value: `if (currentPage.indexOf("?") != -1) currentPage = currentPage.substring(0,currentPage.indexOf("?"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.lavaLamp li:has(a[href="'+location.href.split("/").reverse()[0]+'"])').addClass('current');
```

would that work?

Comment: Don't forget to do a parent() to get the li rather than setting the class on the a...

Comment: @joseph: you may also be better off using pathname instead of href since I belive href will be giving you all the querystring stuff as well (if there is any) which pathname shouldn't.

Comment: @Chris I added that because of `<a href="contact.php?page=contact">Contact</a>` :P

Comment: @hamp13 very sorry... found a bug in the code.  Try that one :P

Comment: @Joseph: Excellent point. Funnily enough I made the comment on that one not working with pathname somewhere but I think I may have deleted it. From the comment as well as my brain. ;-)

Comment: thanks joseph i dont know why ur code not working. i dicieded to choose @package answer but on his code i have little problem his code not working on my contact page coz browser have extra variable can u help me to fix that i am new and trying to learn jquery please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your subfolder. In the case of `http://example.com/mysite/index.php` window.location.pathname should return `/mysite/index.php`. You are then saying that the anchor href (eg `index.php`) must match this which it clearly doesn't. You want to work out a more robust check for whether it is the same page. I'd suggest actually just having the server determine this since when it is running it will clearly know what page it is on. You can do it simply the way others have suggested if the site only has pages in that one folder but if you have pages in subfolders then it may get more confused...

Additionally to set the class on the `li` then once you have your a then you just need to do siomething like:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('current');
```